# Django view with get context not working

Tags: python, django

Have a quick question.  Trying to use a relational model in one DetailView.  However, no matter what I try the data does not display.  I've tried a few versions of template tags to no avail.

html

```
 {% for parts in relatedparts %}{{ parts.name }} 
                                                                </div>{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class ErrorCodeView(DetailView):
context_object_name = 'error_code_details'
model = models.ErrorCodes
template_name = 'error_code_details.html'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # xxx will be available in the template as the related objects
    context = super(ErrorCodeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['relatedparts'] = RelatedParts.objects.filter(name=self.get_object())
    return context
```

models.py

```
class ErrorCodes(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
instructions = models.CharField(max_length=256)
PartsNeeded = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')
usercomments = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='', blank=True)
relpic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/',blank=True)
relpictwo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/',blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("errorcodes:errorcodeview",kwargs={'name':self.name})  

class RelatedParts(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
related_error_code = models.ForeignKey(ErrorCodes, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: nothing is coming up in the html, view is rendering though

Comment: What is `relatedparts_list`? It looks like you should simply use `% for parts in relatedparts %}`.

Comment: yeah I changed that and it didn't resolve.  Nothing shows still

Comment: Does your query actually return anything? Try `print`ing the result of `RelatedParts.objects.filter(name=self.get_object())`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do this at all. You can follow the relationship in the template.

```
{% for part in object.relatedparts_set.all %}{{ part.name }}{% endfor %}
```

You don't need any code in the view to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that "name=self.get_object()" should be "name=self.get_object().name" ?

You currently have:

```
context['relatedparts'] = RelatedParts.objects.filter(name=self.get_object())
```

but that is probably producing an empty queryset.